# Can't open Google Chrome, can't search applications in dash, startup applications stopped running

Tags: unity, 14.04, google-chrome, unity-dash

I am experiencing many issues with my fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04:

- I can't open Google Chrome from the sidebar.
- I can't search any applications in the dash.
- f.lux and Screencloud have stopped running on startup.

As far as I can recall I began experiencing these issues after setting up the Google App Engine SDK for PHP, but it's possible this is being caused by something else entirely.

Running `google-chrome` in the terminal returns:

```
[6119:6119:0511/161156:ERROR:process_singleton_linux.cc(903)] Failed to create socket directory.
[6119:6119:0511/161156:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1198)] Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now to avoid profile corruption.
```

Screencloud displays an alert box on startup saying

> ScreenCloud is already running. Please close the running instance before starting a new one.

Lastly, there is an error icon in the system tray which has displayed a few different error messages:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EeQy.jpg
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCGvs.jpg

I have researched each of these issues individually, tried every solution I could find, rebooted a hundred times, but nothing has changed. What can I do?

Comment: please add more info: did this happen after an upgrade to 14.04? Or did you do a clean install? When did this issue start?

Comment: @JohnnyD. Thanks for the feedback, I've edited the post. This is a clean install of 14.04. This started after I set up the Google App Engine SDK for PHP.

Comment: @JohnnyD. I have run those commands before multiple times. I tried it again and it updated some packages as expected. In particular, it updated `wine-compholio-i386`, which is the package mentioned in the screenshot. I have rebooted, and now I'm getting a different error message in the system tray: http://imgur.com/LtKoqAy

Comment: @JohnnyD. It did not tell me about broken packages or unmet dependencies. I ran the update commands again and it didn't tell me that either.

Comment: @JohnnyD. However, when I ran `sudo chmod 1777 /tmp` followed by `sudo google-chrome` it gave me a different error about startup applications (I didn't make note of it). After `sudo reboot` everything started working again. All the issues I mentioned are fixed. Thank you!

Comment: @JohnnyD. Yes, everything is working. I was worried that I would have to reinstall, but it looks like that chmod magically put everything into its place. Please do convert it to an answer. :)

Comment: I wrote an answer which you can except as it solves your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem needs to give `sudo` permissions to `/tmp` it is where those/certain programs/apps write their temporary stuff to. For this run in Terminal:

```
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
```